# Use template parameter type inside #define

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

The context of my situation is pretty hard to explain exhaustively here but : I am using an external toolset (lib, bins, etc.) which generates some c++ code from a proprietary IDL file. For a given type `T`, it generates a `T_Result` class. The generated code is then integrated to my project.

Now, I am trying to generate a type based on the type of a template parameter.

```
#define GENTYPE(x) x ## _Result

// class coming from generated includes. Copied here for clarity.
class int_Result
{};

template < class T >
class Connector
{
    GENTYPE(T) _result;
public:

};

int main()
{
    Connector<int> t;
    /* ... */
}
```

Of course, this does not work because the c-preprocessor uses the `T` value as it, so the `GENTYPE` macro is expanded inside the Connector class as `T_Result` instead of the wanted `int_Result` class.

One could use `#define` to produce the whole class but then very difficult to maintain, debug, etc.

Does anyone knows a trick to achieve this goal ?

Comment: If you can use C++11, I recommend looking into the [using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) alias. It works well for templating.

Comment: Can you just make your template have two template parameters, one for the class and one for its result?

template<class T, class R> 
...
Connector<int, int_Result> t;

Comment: @rgoble :  I want (need) everything inside the template class. I can not declare the synthetic int_Result class outside the template.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a macro generating `Connector`, we use a macro to generate a traits class that maps `T` to `T_result`.  Then `Connector` just uses that traits class.

```
template<class T>struct result_type;

#define MRT(T) \
  template<>struct result_type<T>{ \
    using type = GENTYPE(T); \
  }

template<class T>using result_t=typename result_type<T>::type;
```

now simply do a `MRT(int);` to make `result_t<int>` be to `int_result`.  The macro must be used before the first use of `result_t<int>`.  Failure to do `MRT(int)` makes `result_t<int>` an error.

This assumes C++11 support: it is 2015.

In `Connector` just do `result_t<T> _result;`

Use of `MRT` is optional, as a strait

```
template<>struct result_type<int>{ using type=GENTYPE(int); };
```

or even

```
template<>struct result_type<int>{ using type=int_result; };
```

isn't all that verbose, and reduces the number of layers of macros.  It does violate DRY (don't repeat yourself) however.

Comment: I want (need) everything inside the template class. I can not declare the synthetic `int_Result` class outside the template.

Comment: @norisknofun I do not see how your comment is related to my answer.  Can you be more clear?

Comment: the `int_Result`  class should not be referenced outside the scope of the `Connector` class. Which leads to the same problem : the preprocessor will consider the `T` char instead of the real class `T=int`

Comment: @norisknofun why should it not be referenced outside of the scope of the `Connector` class?  Arbitrary restrictions that makes no sense are not helpful: explain why please.  Ok, attempting to read your mind: My code *does not* declare a type `int_Result` or `int_result`.  It defines `result_t<int>` as an alias to a type `int_Result` that must be declared by *someone* (such as your generated include file).

Comment: I agree. This constraint is related to the project. The `Connector` class will be exposed via a shared lib. The clients of this shared lib should not be aware of this generated class ...